# Write boldface text using Console.WriteLine (C#) or printfn (F#)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, f#, console

Is there a quick way to write boldface text using `Console.WriteLine` (*C#*) or `printfn` (*F#*)?

If not boldface, perhaps some other kind of visual differentiator, like underlined text?

Comment: Check if you are fine with my edit of the title of your post (feel free to revert). Thank you notes are very optional - accept/comment instead (thanks for that :))

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, sure thing.  This edited version is more compact.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set the [Console.ForegroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx). Click the link, there is a very good example provided in the MSDN.

Fonts and Styles are not available on a per-word basis. To get bold, italics, underline or size, you would have to change *all* text in the Console.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("Test Text");

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("Test Text 2");

Console.ResetColor(); // To return colors back
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will accept this answer as soon as my timeout window has expired.  (Eleven minutes to go.)

Comment: +1 however, usually you're expected to give some code snippet...even if you just copy/paste it from the given link. Links may become unavailable

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov feel free to edit the answer if you feel you can improve it.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Manuel Riezebosch's library https://github.com/riezebosch/Crayon. The library uses ANSI codes to get Bold, Underline, Reversed, Dim decorators to work on console output.

```
using static Crayon.Output;

Console.WriteLine(Green($"green {Red($"{Bold("bold")} red")} green"));
Console.WriteLine(Bold().Green().Text($"starting green {Red("then red")} must be green again"));
```

A point to note is that, though ANSI codes work directly on Linux and Mac terminals,  on Windows 10 it needs to be explicitly enabled and this is done by the library. https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling